# HTTP status code for 'Loading'

Tags: http, client, status

A server receives a request, but decides that the request will take to long to process, so it responds with a site saying *Loading...*. The site will refresh itself until the client receives the response indicating that the (first) request has been completely processed.

What's the most appropriate status code for this *Loading...* site?

My guess is that it is *202 Accepted*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is a request/response protocol. Each request returns a single response.

In your example, the initial request *successfully* returns your loading page, and so the "*success*" 200 code is appropriate.

Your example of this page then generating further data is working at a different layer to HTTP, and so doesn't need to add semantics to the HTTP level

Comment: I'd generally agree, except if 'processing' could be consider an error-state. a 5xx _might_ also be appropriate for those cases. Maybe a `503` with a `Retry-After` header. I don't think the `200` for the loading page is appropriate, if the 'loading page' is not considered to be the 'state' of the resource. Or maybe a `404` because the resource could be considered 'not yet found'.

Comment: I don't want to do hair splitting here but jut to be technically correct, a final response may be preceded by any number of interim responses 1xx (since HTTP/1.0).

Answer (score 0):

For a service that can not give full data response because it's still loading - [evert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80911/evert) suggestion in the comments is the best.

Return `503 / Service Unavailable` status, if you can estimate the time the service take to load - add [`Retry-After` Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After).