# HTTP code for timeout when server continues processing in the background

Tags: http, web

I stumbled upon a case where a request to an endpoint might take more than 60 seconds (let's say that's the timeout value), in which case the server sends a response and continues processing the request in the background. There are also cases where the same request would be processed before it times out and a successful response would be sent from the server to the client.

What would be the best HTTP code to use in those first case? I read [HTTP server timeout. When should it be sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451196/http-server-timeout-when-should-it-be-sent/), which suggests 503 or 504, and [HTTP status code for 'Loading'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011333/http-status-code-for-loading), which mentions that the request can be deemed successful and return 200. But I'm not convinced by any of those suggestions more than the others yet.

Comment: They will receive the response through a webhook request once it is processed, so I don't think a queue and polling is necessary. But your suggestion is similar to Charlie's comment, 200 might be best. But what worries me is that technically I'm not sure I can say that the request will be 100% processed successfully, although that is the expected behaviour if no unexpected events occur.

Answer (score 0):

**No**

HTTP protocol doesn't work that way.

A server would receive a request, process it and sends a reply. The cycle ends there.

HTTP is never intended to send multui-stage replies with different states. You need to work on a custom protocol built on top of HTTP if you want to do that.

Sending timeout error as an indication of an unfinished response is an anti pattern. If your server takes more time than usual to process a request, you should send a **success** response with an ID which can be used to poll the state of the initial request and get the results.

Comment: The idea is not to send multiple replies, just one. It's just that in some cases the processing is successful before timeout, in others it is successful after timeout, and, naturally, there may be unsuccessful cases too, but the case here is about the presumably successful ones. I see, however, that a success response might make sense. About the results - they will get them through a webhook request, so they won't need to poll for them.

Comment: In this case it looks that its all about fine tuning timeouts.

Comment: That is also possible, but in some cases it can take about 10 minutes. If it was around 1-2 minutes I think it'd be a good idea to consider increasing the timeout, but more than that inconveniences the client in my opinion.

Comment: So, this is a design issue of a system which can take a lot of time for a request to be processed. If that is a feature of the system, it should offer polling.

Answer (score 0):

So to summarize from your question and comments: you have an HTTP API that takes a command and executes it, and sends a callback-reply through a webhook. If the execution takes longer than a minute, you have to send some form of reply that indicates the request is still being processed.

There are various problems with executing long-running work in an HTTP request handler. For starters, you tie up HTTP server resources (threads, sockets) while processing non-HTTP work, you can't restart the HTTP server without losing work, and so on.

So I would opt for a queuing mechanism that takes in the work, replies 200 OK or 201 Created immediately, and then schedules the work for processing on a background thread or even a different service. When finished, you execute the webhook callback.

Any error response to the initial call will leave the caller confused: they won't know whether their requested work will finish, unless you use an "exotic" status code that actually differs from real error conditions, and document that they can expect that.

Comment: This is essentially how it operates currently, but I was wondering what response code would if it best. I probably misunderstood your queue and polling suggestion earlier. Well, there is no polling API exposed, but there could be if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Charlie and CodeCaster suggested to return 200 or 201 and I took a look at the other 2xx codes and found 202 Accepted:

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 202 Accepted response status
> code indicates that the request has been accepted for processing, but
> the processing has not been completed; in fact, processing may not
> have started yet. The request might or might not eventually be acted
> upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.
>
> 202 is non-committal, meaning that there is no way for the HTTP to
> later send an asynchronous response indicating the outcome of
> processing the request. It is intended for cases where another process
> or server handles the request, or for batch processing.

I wonder if this would fit best.